# Parse Additional Fields in ELK

Tags: elk, amazon-cloudtrail

Scenario: CloudTrail Logs JSON Ingestion in SOF-ELK

```
{
  "eventVersion": "1.08",
  "userIdentity": {
    "type": "Root",
    "principalId": "107513503799",
    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::107513503799:root",
    "accountId": "107513503799",
    "accessKeyId": "ASIARSCCN4A34LC6MFWG",
    "sessionContext": {
      "sessionIssuer": {},
      "webIdFederationData": {},
      "attributes": {
        "creationDate": "2023-08-26T18:45:20Z",
        "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
      }
    }
  },
  "eventTime": "2023-08-26T20:30:05Z",
  "eventSource": "organizations.amazonaws.com",
  "eventName": "ListDelegatedAdministrators",
  "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
  "sourceIPAddress": "84.32.71.36",
  "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
  "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:iam::107513503799:root is not authorized to perform: organizations:ListDelegatedAdministrators on resource: * because no resource-based policy allows the organizations:ListDelegatedAdministrators action",
  "requestParameters": null,
  "responseElements": null,
  "requestID": "aa322cbd-e252-4aeb-b487-dff760dfe955",
  "eventID": "68ae037e-cb86-4174-bc15-b6aadc6f327b",
  "readOnly": true,
  "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
  "managementEvent": true,
  "recipientAccountId": "107513503799",
  "eventCategory": "Management",
  "tlsDetails": {
    "tlsVersion": "TLSv1.3",
    "cipherSuite": "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "clientProvidedHostHeader": "organizations.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "sessionCredentialFromConsole": "true"
}
```

Fields such as errorCode, errorMessage, requestParameters etc. are not populated as fields when I upload the JSON because they are empty in some events but I really want it to populate everything. When I use Splunk and upload the JSON, it populates all the fields.
In SOF-ELK what additional configuration should I do and where?

From Splunk when I upload the JSON:
[image]

Comment: Can you shed some more light on how you configured SOF-ELK? According to [this filter configuration](https://github.com/philhagen/sof-elk/blob/main/configfiles/6901-aws.conf#L38C1-L39), the error fields are passed along

Comment: Do you see monthly indexes called `aws-YYYY.MM`?

Comment: Thank you kind gentlemen! Phil fixed it in Issue 293 raised by me :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now fixed in the original repo!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).